# Passing variable between functions in a service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been searching for an answer to this, and cannot seem to find anything. I have a service, in the first block I am successfully logging a url that I then need to pass into my `getData()` function. But it comes back undefined, I have tried the method below, and I tried moving the first `$http.get` into the controller where I am calling it, as well as moving the first $http.get into the `getData()` function. Am I going about this all wrong?

```
di.service('testService', function($http) {
    $http.get('https://us.api.data/tichondrius?locale=en_US&apikey=xxxxxxxx').
    then(function(response) {
        var urlToJsonFileUncut = response.data.files[0].url;
        console.log(urlToJsonFileUncut);
        urlToJsonFile = urlToJsonFileUncut.slice(7);
        console.log(urlToJsonFile);
        return urlToJsonFile;
    });
    this.getData = function(urlToJsonFile) {
        console.log(urlToJsonFile);
        return $http.get('http://localhost:1337/' + urlToJsonFile).
    then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.realms[0].name);
        return response.data.realms[0].name;
    });
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` is an async request. so you need to chain it inside the first request  to ensure the value of first response is available when second request is called.

```
di.service('testService', function($http) {
  var getData = function () {
    return $http.get('https://us.api.data/tichondrius?locale=en_US&apikey=xxxxxxxx').
    then(function(response) {
      var urlToJsonFileUncut = response.data.files[0].url;
      console.log(urlToJsonFileUncut);
      var urlToJsonFile = urlToJsonFileUncut.slice(7);
      console.log(urlToJsonFile);

      $http.get('http://localhost:1337/' + urlToJsonFile).
      then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.realms[0].name);
        return response.data.realms[0].name;
      });
    });
  }

  return { getData: getData; }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a **factory** instead of a **service**

**Check out the below code**

```
di.factory('testService', function ($http) {
    var variable_name;

    var serviceMethodName = function () {
        $http.get('https://us.api.data/tichondrius?locale=en_US&apikey=xxxxxxxx').
        then(function (response) {
            var urlToJsonFileUncut = response.data.files[0].url;
            console.log(urlToJsonFileUncut);
            urlToJsonFile = urlToJsonFileUncut.slice(7);
            console.log(urlToJsonFile);
            variable_name = urlToJsonFile;          //added 
        });
    }

    //modified parameter in below method
    var getData = function (variable_name) {

        var urlToJsonFile = variable_name;          //added 
        console.log(urlToJsonFile);
        return $http.get('http://localhost:1337/' + urlToJsonFile).
    then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.realms[0].name);
        return response.data.realms[0].name;
    });

    }

    //Exposes the two methods and accessbile through out the app unless it is modified
    return {
        serviceMethodName: serviceMethodName,
        getData:getData
    }

});
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, furthermore I need to also be able to pass in a variable to the service (or factory) from an ng-model, does needing to do that change which of these is more viable?

Comment: Yes you can do that very simple inject your service to controller and use the service variable to assign to $scope. `$scope.variable=testService.variable`